# Possible bug in hypergeometric function AppellF1

Tags: numerics, special-functions

In the context of sums over Legendre polynomials ((1), (2)) I stumbled upon the interesting hypergeometric function `AppellF1[]`.

Unfortunately, the implementation in *Mathematica* appears to have difficulties when it comes to numerical evaluation, including plots.

This behaviour spoils to a large degree the "success" of having obtained closed form expressions.

I would consider this a bug.

```
$Version

(* Out[2944]= "10.1.0  for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)" *)
```

$$\\$$

*Example 1*: `Plot3D`, real arguments

As a compact example, consider this plotting command

```
Plot3D[{Re[AppellF1[-(1/2), -(1/2), -(1/2), 1/2, x, y]], 
  Im[AppellF1[-(1/2), -(1/2), -(1/2), 1/2, x, y]]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image: plot]

We see that the "corners" are cut out despite the fact that `AppellF1[]` is well defined for `Abs[x] < 1` and `Abs[y] < 1`.

$$\\$$

*Example 2*: numerical value at a specific points

2a. What is the numerical value of this expression (which appears naturally in the summation problem mentioned in the beginning)

```
AppellF1[-(1/2), -(1/2), -(1/2), 1/2, E^((2 I π)/3), 
  E^(-((2 I π)/3))] // N

(* Out[2973]= AppellF1[-0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.5, -0.5 + 0.866025 I, -0.5 - 0.866025 I]
```

$$\\$$

2b. Particular results in the "buggy" region of `Plot3D`

```
AppellF1[-(1/2), -(1/2), -(1/2), 1/2, 0.9, 0.9] // N

(* Out[3091]= 1.9 *)
```

There seems to be no problem.

Generally, these special cases do not have difficulties

```
AppellF1[-(1/2), -(1/2), -(1/2), 1/2, x, x] // FullSimplify

(* Out[3093]= 1 + x *)

AppellF1[-(1/2), -(1/2), -(1/2), 1/2, x, -x] // FullSimplify

(* Out[3094]= Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), -(1/4), 3/4, x^2] *)
```

But consider this case with x = 0.9 and y = 0.8:

```
AppellF1[-(1/2), -(1/2), -(1/2), 1/2, 0.9, 0.8] // N

(* Out[3119]= AppellF1[-0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 0.9, 0.8] *)
```

Here no numerical value is returned.

Whereas, e.g.

```
AppellF1[-(1/2), -(1/2), -(1/2), 1/2, 0.5, 0.6] // N

(* 1.55065 *)
```

$$\\$$

Example 3a: `Plot`

This plot takes about 5 minutes on my PC:

```
Plot[Re[AppellF1[-(1/2), -(1/2), -(1/2), 1/2, E^(I θ), 
    E^(-I θ)] /. {d -> 1/2}], {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image: plot]

Notice the numerical difficulties close to the ends of the interval and the broad gap in the middle.

Example 3b: `ListLinePlot`

The coarse-grained alternative is

```
Table[{θ, 
   AppellF1[-d, -(1/2), -(1/2), 1 - d, E^(I θ), 
     E^(-I θ)] /. {d -> 1/2}}, {θ, 0, 2 π, π/10}];

Chop[N[%], 10^-5]

(* Out[2993]= {{0, 2.}, {0.314159, 1.90825}, {0.628319, 
  1.7056}, {0.942478, 1.44035}, {1.25664, 1.14516}, {1.5708, 
  0.847213}, {1.88496, 0.569869}, {2.19911, 0.332818}, {2.51327, 
  0.151856}, {2.82743, 
  AppellF1[-0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 
   0.5, -0.951057 + 0.309017 I, -0.951057 - 0.309017 I]}, {3.14159, 
  0}, {3.45575, 
  AppellF1[-0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 
   0.5, -0.951057 - 0.309017 I, -0.951057 + 0.309017 I]}, {3.76991, 
  0.151856}, {4.08407, 0.332818}, {4.39823, 0.569869}, {4.71239, 
  0.847213}, {5.02655, 1.14516}, {5.34071, 1.44035}, {5.65487, 
  1.7056}, {5.96903, 1.90825}, {6.28319, 2.}} *)

ListLinePlot[%]
```

[image]

The numerical chopping takes a few minutes before we can `ListLinePlot` the list.
We can see that the gap in the middle of the graph is caused by non evaluated functions `AppellF1`.

$$\\$$

*Some definitions* (cf. (3))

Series representation

$$F1(a,b_1,b_2,c,x,y) = \sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{ (a)_{m+n} }{(c)_{m+n}} (b_1)_m (b_2)_n \frac {x^m}{m!} \frac {y^n}{n!} $$

```
Sum[
 Pochhammer[a, m + n]/
  Pochhammer[c, n + m] Pochhammer[b1, m] Pochhammer[b2, n] x^m/m! y^n/
  n!, {m, 0, ∞}, {n, 0, ∞}]

(* Out[2843]= AppellF1[a, b1, b2, c, x, y] *)
```

Integral representation ((3) formula (9))

$$F1(a,b_1,b_2,c,x,y) = \frac{\Gamma (c)}{\Gamma (a) \Gamma (c-a)} \int_0^1 t^{a-1} (1-t)^{-a+c-1} (1-t x)^{-b_1} (1-t y)^{-b_2} \, dt$$

```
fctF1[a_, b1_, b2_, c_, x_, y_] := 
 Gamma[c]/(Gamma[a] Gamma[c - a])
   Integrate[
   t^(a - 1) (1 - t)^(c - a - 1) (1 - x t)^-b1 (1 - t y)^-b2, {t, 0, 
    1}]
```

References

(1) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2111566/summation-of-legendre-polynomials-sum-l-2-infty-frac2l1l1kl1/2116383#2116383

(2)   [Summation of Legendre polynomials related to the zeta function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138542/summation-of-legendre-polynomials-related-to-the-zeta-function)

(3) http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AppellHypergeometricFunction.html

Comment: I would most certainly report this to WRI.

Comment: Because AppellF1[-(1/2), -(1/2), -(1/2), 1/2, 0.9, -0.9] outputs $1.15196$, this seems to be  a graphic problem.

Comment: @user64494 No, try this AppellF1[-(1/2), -(1/2), -(1/2), 1/2, x, y] /. {x -> 0.9, y -> 0.91} // N (* Out[3023]= AppellF1[-0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 0.9, 0.91] *) The function is not evaluated. That's the bug.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze This one is now good in 13.3.0 in the cloud and prints 1.90501. And so does the two other examples, one prints 0.406299-5.55112*^-17 I and the other 1.85109

Comment: @ Валерий Заподовников Thank you for the good news. I'll check it once I have this version.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze BTW, the bug with https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/172425/82985 is still there (look up the comment from Tyma Gaidash there, looks very relevant), and the plots here all fail now, apparently? Why is that?

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Did you check it?

Comment: No, Valeri, I didn't check it as I don't have the new version. I trust in your efforts.

Answer (score 11):

The method I am about to propose is a bit finicky, and thus requires some manual intervention and checking. With that caveat, here is a method to evaluate the first Appell hypergeometric function for arguments where the built-in `AppellF1[]` fails.

This is a combination of two methods: a method, due to [Cuyt](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01390216), for transforming a double series into a sequence, and the Wynn $\varepsilon$ algorithm.

Normally, one would use Wynn through the built-in *undocumented* function `` NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit[] `` (`SequenceLimit[]` in older versions), but I have found it unstable in this situation. Thus, I fell back to using my own implementation, implemented as the [van den Broeck-Schwartz form](https://doi.org/10.1137/0510061):

```
wgvs[seq_?VectorQ, h_: 1] := Module[{n = Length[seq], ep, v, w},
     Table[ep[k] = seq[[k]]; w = 0;
           Do[v = w; w = ep[j]; 
              ep[j] = v If[OddQ[k - j], h, 1] + 1/(ep[j + 1] - w),
              {j, k - 1, 1, -1}];
           ep[Mod[k, 2, 1]], {k, n}]]
```

Now, let's present the method. For reference, let's take a case where the built-in `AppellF1[]` evaluates numerically, for comparison purposes:

```
With[{a = -1/2, b1 = -1/2, b2 = -1/2, c = 1/2, x = 3/4, y = 2/3}, 
     res = N[AppellF1[a, b1, b2, c, x, y], 30]]
   1.70889493846451655825978155908
```

Here is Cuyt's method for summing the defining double series:

```
With[{a = -1/2, b1 = -1/2, b2 = -1/2, c = 1/2, x = 3/4, y = 2/3},
     seq = N[Accumulate[Table[Sum[Function[{i, j}, 
                                           Pochhammer[a, i + j]/Pochhammer[c, i + j]
                                           Pochhammer[b1, i] Pochhammer[b2, j]
                                           x^i/i! y^j/j!] @@ v,
                                  {v, FrobeniusSolve[{1, 1}, k]}], {k, 0, 39}]], 60]];
```

Note the need to use 1. a large number of terms, and 2. very high precision. This is because there will inevitably some numerical cancellation during the application of Wynn $\varepsilon$.

You might be tempted to just take the last entry of `seq`, but that's not a very accurate result…

```
Last[seq] - res
   -1.3407389500737610211*10^-10
```

…yet. This is where Wynn $\varepsilon$ comes in:

```
eps = wgvs[seq];

Take[eps, -10] - res
   {-4.78916651602*10^-18, -1.42635137821*10^-18, -3.7802058433*10^-19,
    -7.57389529*10^-21, 1.0837220906*10^-19, 1.4919244639*10^-19,
    1.6200922471*10^-19, 1.6650702861*10^-19, 1.6792388370*10^-19, 
    1.6841995299*10^-19}
```

and we see that the results are much better after acceleration.

Now, let's use the OP's complex example, where `AppellF1[]` is not able to evaluate numerically:

```
With[{a = -1/2, b1 = -1/2, b2 = -1/2, c = 1/2, x = Exp[2 I π/3], y = Exp[-2 I π/3]},
     N[AppellF1[a, b1, b2, c, x, y], 20] // Head] (* does not evaluate *)
   AppellF1

With[{a = -1/2, b1 = -1/2, b2 = -1/2, c = 1/2, x = Exp[2 I π/3], y = Exp[-2 I π/3]},
     seq = N[Accumulate[Table[Sum[Function[{i, j}, 
                                           Pochhammer[a, i + j]/Pochhammer[c, i + j]
                                           Pochhammer[b1, i] Pochhammer[b2, j]
                                           x^i/i! y^j/j!] @@ v,
                                  {v, FrobeniusSolve[{1, 1}, k]}], {k, 0, 39}]], 60]];
```

Since we don't know the result in advance, we will be a bit more conservative. First, take the differences of the transformed partial sums:

```
Differences[Take[seq, -10]] // Chop // N
   {-0.0000182151, -0.0000474801, 0.0000594675, -0.000014441, -0.000037797,
    0.0000476935, -0.0000116771, -0.0000306683, 0.0000389418}
```

and we see that they only agree to four or so digits. Now, apply `wgvs[]`:

```
eps = wgvs[seq];
```

and look at the differences again:

```
Differences[Take[eps, -10]] // N
   {-4.86267*10^-17 + 0. I, 3.14393*10^-17 + 0. I, 6.35936*10^-18 + 0. I,
    -1.57739*10^-18 + 0. I, 9.1468*10^-20 + 0. I, -1.62375*10^-19 + 0. I, 
    2.81443*10^-19 + 0. I, -1.45097*10^-20 + 0. I, 3.98562*10^-21 + 0. I}
```

and we now get agreement to twenty or so digits, so we can take the last one as a provisional result:

```
Last[eps] // Re
   0.40629888645996024661252095193
```

---

**Addendum 7/25/2019**

As it turns out, this Appell value that cannot be evaluated by *Mathematica* has a relatively simple closed form in terms of complete elliptic integrals (derived after some amount of used paper):

```
N[2 EllipticE[1/4] - 3/2 EllipticK[1/4], 30]
   0.406298886459960246612785047283
```

and we see that the double sum evaluated using the accelerated Cuyt transformation has indeed given twenty digits of accuracy.

More generally, we have the result

```
AppellF1[-1/2, -1/2, -1/2, 1/2, x, y] == 
y AppellF1[1/2, -1/2, 1/2, 3/2, x, y] +
x AppellF1[1/2, -1/2, 1/2, 3/2, y, x] + Sqrt[1 - x] Sqrt[1 - y]
```

which can be readily expressed in terms of the [Carlson integrals](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19#PT3) (*Mathematica* package from [here](https://github.com/tpfto/Carlson)):

```
<<Carlson`

4 CarlsonRG[1 - x, 1 - y, 1] + (x + y - 2) CarlsonRF[1 - x, 1 - y, 1] -
Sqrt[1 - x] Sqrt[1 - y]
```

or less elegantly in terms of more conventional special functions,

```
2 Sqrt[x] EllipticE[ArcCos[Sqrt[1 - x]], y/x] +
(y/Sqrt[x] - Sqrt[x]) InverseJacobiCN[Sqrt[1 - x], y/x] +
Sqrt[1 - x] Sqrt[1 - y]
```

---

As mentioned, I have found the current version of the accelerated Cuyt method to be finicky and a bit hard to automatize; there are argument ranges where you need to take more terms, higher precision, or both, and I usually make these judgments on convergence based on the behavior of the original and transformed sequences. Nevertheless, someone might be able to build a usable routine based on this someday.

Comment: This now not needed / it just works in 13.3.

Comment: It is 0.40629888645996024661278504728321678779952216344283+0.*10^-51 I