# How is the function AppellF1 implemented internally

Tags: special-functions, implementation-details

In a recent post ([Possible bug in hypergeometric function AppellF1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139400/possible-bug-in-hypergeometric-function-appellf1)) I reported a buggy behaviour of the function AppellF1[].

Now I would like to aks about the implementation which possibly can explain this behaviour, and specifically the appearance of the octogonal region in (x,y) where the implementation of the function is well-behaved. (I'm asking also because I have not received an answer to that post).

There are two definitions for AppellF1[] which could be used for an implementation ( http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AppellHypergeometricFunction.html  )

Series representation

$$F1(a,b1,b2,c,x,y) = \sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{ (a)_{m+n} }{(c)_{m+n}} (\text{b1})_m (\text{b2})_n \frac {x^m}{m!} \frac {y^n}{n!} $$

```
Sum[
 Pochhammer[a, m + n]/
  Pochhammer[c, n + m] Pochhammer[b1, m] Pochhammer[b2, n] x^m/m! y^n/
  n!, {m, 0, \[Infinity]}, {n, 0, \[Infinity]}]

(* Out[2843]= AppellF1[a, b1, b2, c, x, y] *)
```

Integral representation

$$F1(a,b1,b2,c,x,y) = \frac{\Gamma (c)}{\Gamma (a) \Gamma (c-a)} \int_0^1 t^{a-1} (1-t)^{-a+c-1} (1-t x)^{-\text{b1}} (1-t y)^{-\text{b2}} \, dt$$

```
fctF1[a_, b1_, b2_, c_, x_, y_] := 
 Gamma[c]/(Gamma[a] Gamma[c - a])
   Integrate[
   t^(a - 1) (1 - t)^(c - a - 1) (1 - x t)^-b1 (1 - t y)^-b2, {t, 0, 
    1}]
```

Comment: Has my answer below answered your question of "How is the function AppelF1 implemented internally?"

Comment: Yes, thank you it has. I have just confirmed this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems the whole code for `AppellF1` is implemented in the Wolfram Language, and can be viewed using `PrintDefinitions` from the `` GeneralUtilities` `` package:

```
<< GeneralUtilities`
PrintDefinitions[AppellF1]
```

For numerical evaluation, the third definition is used, which calls `` System`AppellF1Dump`NHypergeometricF1 ``

You can see the source code by following the link, or by running

```
PrintDefinitions[System`AppellF1Dump`NHypergeometricF1]
```

Both representations mentioned by OP are being used.  But one can see, by looking at the pattern conditions, that the function is not implemented  for all cases.

Comment: Well, now it is. In 13.3.