# Evaluating Lauricella functions of Third kind numerically in Mathematica

Tags: numerics, special-functions

Let's consider the Lauricella function of third kind, denote as $F_{C}(a,b;c_1,...,c_n;x_1,...x_n)$ in [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LauricellaFunctions.html). Is anyone aware of an algorithm that allows to numerically evaluate such a function for the case $n=3$ ?

I tried to have a look at the literature on the topic, but I did not find anything (but I'm not an expert :-)).

Many thanks

Comment: Hi, have you looked at this answer? J.M has a thorough analysis on these functions https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154434/evaluating-lauricella-functions-in-mathematica

Comment: Thanks, I read that answer. Unfortunately  it discusses only the case of a Lauricella function of fourth kind (at least that's my level of understanding).

Comment: I am not an expert on the matter, but if I am not confused myself too much, I think that the approach there should also work for the case n=3. For the three variate case, do you know any results against which I can check and let you know?

Comment: Oh I see, then I will try. Unfortunately I'm not aware of any known results :-(

Comment: What I did in that other answer is indeed only applicable to $F_D$; for $F_C$, a more general procedure like Cuyt's transformation (used [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/169860)) would need to be employed.

Comment: I see, many thanks :-)