# Error in integral representation of Appell's series

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions

It was originally asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2763362/).

According to [About the confluent versions of Appell Hypergeometric Function and Lauricella Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/812748/about-the-confluent-versions-of-appell-hypergeometric-function-and-lauricella-fu) the integral

$$\int_0^1t^{a-1}(1-t)^{c-a-1}(1-xt)^{-b}e^{yt}~dt $$

can be expressed as

$$\int_0^1t^{a-1}(1-t)^{c-a-1}(1-xt)^{-b}e^{yt}~dt=\dfrac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(c-a)}{\Gamma(c)}\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}F_1\left(a,b,k,c;x,\dfrac{y}{k}\right).$$

**It look like true**, but gives numeric error. Look that, calculated by Mathematica:

```
F[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[t^(a - 1) (1 - t)^(c - a - 1) (1 - x t)^(-b) Exp[ y t], {t, 0, 1}]

N[F[3/2, 1, 2, .4, .3], 20]
{2.8964403550198865`}

G[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
 Gamma[a] Gamma[c - a]/Gamma[c] Limit[AppellF1[a, b, k, c, x, y/k],k -> Infinity]

N[G[3/2, 1, 2, .4, .3], 20] 
{2.2854650559595466`}
```

where I was careful to ensure that $|x|<1,|y|<1$, and $\text{Re}(c)>\text{Re}(a)>0$, which are the condition of $F_1$.Note that the results are different. Furthermore, according to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5BAppellF1%5B3%2F2,+1,+k,++2,+x,+y%2Fk%5D,+++k+-%3E+Infinity%5D)

$$\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty}F_1[3/2,1,k;2;0.4,\text{any/k}]=1.4549$$

So, is It a math issue or Mathematica issue?

Comment: Question to other users: should we include the tag [tag:bugs]?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Did you report this bug to Mathematica? Do you know if they fixed it?

Comment: In my 13.1 you now need to Rationalize to get to your N[,20] result. N[G[3/2, 1, 2, 4/10, 3/10], 20]. And F[3/2, 1, 2, 4/10, 3/10] does not give normal symbolic form (anymore?), and thus does not allow N manipulation, it is small. WorlframAlpha gives -5+5 Sqrt[5/3] for your x = 4/10 and so does 13.1.

Comment: Oh, yes! I got why it is so "cool" now for N[F[3/2, 1, 2, 0.4, .3], 20], that it cannot even listen to N[]! See, if you will change the first NIntegrate to Integrate it will actually produce an integrand from which it is calculated, but will fail to even find the antiderivative! Wow! And then you can just change Integrate to NIntegrate back again. Another bug 
in there (though 2.8964403550198865 is the correct result, it is G that has a problem). NIntegrate[(E^(3 t/10) Sqrt[t])/( Sqrt[1 - t] (1 - (2 t)/5)), {t, 0, 1}, PrecisionGoal -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 50]

Comment: @ Валерий Заподовников
 Replacing Infinity in G by a large number, say 100 or 200, leads to a good approximation $G \simeq F$. Hance the limit is the problem. Sorry, I saw afterwards that this defect was already noticed by others.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze I was wrong here too. You see when you copy the result it expands. So, even if it looks like 2.89644 in the notebook when you copy it gets you to 2.8964403550198865 with that grave accent symbol, as in here. Also did you see comment below about "error still exists as the link should give". You only get that result after //Simplify though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a bug in the calculation of the large $k$ limit of `AppellF1`. This is easy to illustrate:

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]
wrongLimit = Limit[AppellF1[3/2, 1, k, 2, 4/10, (3/10)/k], k -> Infinity];
correctLimit = NLimit[AppellF1[3/2, 1, k, 2, 4/10, (3/10)/k], k -> Infinity];
Plot[{AppellF1[3/2, 1, k, 2, 4/10, (3/10)/k], wrongLimit, correctLimit}, {k, .5, 5}
, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Directive[Red, Dashed], Directive[Green, Dashed]}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 3}}]
```

[image]

Perhaps the bug should be reported. In the meantime, you can use `NLimit` to get the correct limit. If you use `NLimit` in your definition of `G`, you get results that consistent with those of `F` (up to numerical inaccuracy).

Comment: Thank you a lot! I didn't  know 'NLimit'.

Comment: @user3321 I'm glad I could help :-)

Comment: Is it normal this code
 `NLimit[AppellF1[3/2, -1, k,1, 16(1)^2 Sin[Pi/2]^2, -(8 (1)^2 Sin[Pi/2]^2)/k], k -> Infinity]` take a long time?

Comment: I don't know how `NLimit` works internally, so I can't tell. But if you want to accelerate the process, you can use `SequenceLimit[AppellF1[3/2, -1, #, 1, 16, -(8/#)] & /@ N[Range[17, 35, 2]]]`, which yields the approximate limit `0.065` in a few seconds on my PC. It is less reliable than `NLimit`though, so use at your own risk (I plotted the function and it seems that the result is more or less good, but don't take my word for it).

Comment: Unfortunately this result is not correct. The correct result should be $-0.05971141134287522$, which is the result of the integral `NIntegrate[ t^{-1/2} (1-t)^{-1/2} (1-16 Sin[Pi/2]^2 t) Exp[-8 Sin[Pi/2]^2 t], {t, 0, 1}]`. Sorry, but it's a $1/2$ instead of $3/2$. The code with $1/2$ results $-0.06334540766907899$. Maybe the issue is math now. Anyway, thank you again for your help. If you know anything else, let me know, please.

Comment: Why use NIntegrate? Integrate gives Pi ((-7 BesselI[0, 4] + 8 BesselI[1, 4]))/E^4 which is -0.59711.. 7569 (BTW, wrong end of number, not nice).

Comment: The error [still exists](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ddt+lim%5B%28%28b%2F%28b+-+c%29%29%5E%28-q%29+%28%28b+h%29%2F%28-a+%2B+b+h%29%29%5E%28-h%29+%281+%2B+b+t%29%5E%281+%2B+p%29+AppellF1%281+%2B+p%2C+-q%2C+-h%2C+2+%2B+p%2C+-%28c+%2B+b+c+t%29%2F%28b+-+c%29%2C+%28a+%2B+a+b+t%29%2F%28a+-+b+h%29%29%29%2F%28b+%281+%2B+p%29%29%2Ch-%3Einfty%5D) as the link should give $e^{a x}(1+a t)^p(1+b t)^q$

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform  SequenceLimit is now called NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit, still being used. Why, oh, why, LOL...

Comment: @TymaGaidash Can you write your answer? It is probably the bug, indeed.