# Why can't Mathematica compute this integral $ \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{1-a \cos^2x}{1+b\sin^2x} \mathrm e^{-\frac{a}{4}\cos2x}\mathrm d x $?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

This question was also asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2887659/i-really-dont-know-what-else-i-can-do-to-solve-this-integral).

I have faced some difficulties to do the following integral

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{1-a \cos^2x}{1+b\sin^2x}\mathrm e^{-\frac{a}{4}\cos2x}\mathrm d x, $$

where $a$ and $b$ are constants under $x-$variable. I'm sure this can be solved analytically. However, Mathematica doesn't give explicit answer. My code:

```
 Integrate[((1 - a Cos[x]^2) Exp[-a/4 Cos[2 x]])/(1 + b Sin[x]^2), {x,0, Pi/2},
           Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0]
```

I have found a closed expression in terms of Hypergeometric series. It's Something like that:

```
Limit[AppellF1[3/2, 1, 1/k, 2, x, k y], k -> 0],
```

but this not work for me.  If you kindly give me some hint or text such that on going through which I can do it by myself. Thanking you.

**Edit: Solution in terms of $F_1$:**

Here my solution in terms of series. The original integral is that

$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\mathrm d\phi\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm d\theta~\sin\theta\frac{(1-u^2\sin^2\theta\cos^2\phi)\cos^2\theta}{(y^2\cos\phi+x^2\sin^2\phi)\sin^2\theta+x^2y^2\cos^2\theta}\mathrm e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}\sin^2\theta\cos^2\phi}, \tag{1} $$

where $x$, $y$ and $u$ are positive constants. I tried to do the $\phi$ integral first. Letting $I_\phi$ this $\phi$-integral, then:

$$ I_\phi=4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\mathrm d\phi\frac{1-a\cos^2\phi}{A\cos^2\phi+B\sin^2\phi} \mathrm e^{-\frac{a}{2}\cos^2\phi}. $$

The change of variable $\cos^2\phi=t$ give us

$$ I_\phi= \frac{2}{B}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{t}\sqrt{1-t}}\frac{1-at}{1-\nu t}\mathrm e^{-\frac{a}{2}t}, $$

where $B=x^2\sin^2\theta+x^2y^2\cos^2\theta$, $a=u^2\sin^2\theta$, and $\nu=\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+x^2y^2\cot^2\theta}$. According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humbert_series) we have then

$$ I_\phi=\frac{2}{B}\left[B\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},1,-;1;\nu,-\frac{a}{2}\right)-aB\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)F_1\left(\frac{3}{2},1,-;2;\nu,-\frac{a}{2}\right)\right] $$

That is my solution until now.

**Edit 2**

If you prefer, the more general case of the equation (1) is:

$$ I= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\mathrm d\phi\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm d\theta~\sin\theta\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm dr~r^2\frac{\cos(u r \sin\theta \cos\phi)3x^2y^2\cos^2\theta}{(y^2\cos\phi+x^2\sin^2\phi)\sin^2\theta+x^2y^2\cos^2\theta}\mathrm e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}} \tag{2} $$

**EDIT 3**

Here is a solution of the equation $(2)$, wich was found by another person.

$$ I_G=\frac{12 \pi x~y}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \mathrm dk \frac{k^2 \exp\left(-\frac{u^2}{2}\frac{x^2k^2}{(1-x^2)(1-k^2)}\right)}{\sqrt{1-k^2}\sqrt{1-k^2\frac{1-y^2}{1-x^2}}}. $$

Notice that,numerically,

$$ I_G=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} I$$

as you can see in this code performed in Mathematica:

```
IG[x_, y_, u_] := 
 Sqrt[Pi/2] NIntegrate[(12  Pi x y)/(1 - x^2)^(3/2)
(v^2 Exp[-(u^2 x^2 v^2)/(2 (1 - x^2) (1 - v^2))])/(Sqrt[1 - v^2] Sqrt[1 - v^2 (1 - y^2)/(1 - x^2)]), {v, 0, Sqrt[1 - x^2]}]
IG[.3, .4, 1]
** 4.53251 **

I[x_, y_, u_] := 
 NIntegrate[(r^2 Sin[a] Cos[
      u r Sin[a] Cos[b]] 3 x^2 y^2 Cos[a]^2 Exp[-r^2/
       2])/((y^2 Cos[b]^2 + x^2 Sin[b]^2) Sin[a]^2 + 
     x^2 y^2 Cos[a]^2), {r, 0, Infinity}, {a, 0, Pi}, {b, 0, 2 Pi}]
I[.3, .4, 1]
** 4.53251 **
```

Therefore, it is possible to find an elementary closed form for $I_\phi$. What do you say?

**Edit: that is just a detail**

My question comes down to: what steps were taken to get from $I$ to $I_G$.

I let Mathematica run overnight, but it was unable to compute the integral $I$. However, it also didn’t “give up”. What do you say about that? Maybe another CAS will work?

Comment: As for doing integration, you might be interested in [`Rubi`](https://rulebasedintegration.org)

Comment: Why are you sure it can be solved analytically? Both Mathematica and Rubi are unable to do it  with `a=b=1`. And what is wrong with an answer in terms of hypergeometric functions?

Comment: You might want to consider asking from [mathematics site](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ Thank you! I did not know this package.

Comment: @FredSimons I'm sure that this integral is solved analytically because it was solved by an acquaintance of mine. And, apparently, he solved it in terms of elementary functions. That's because my hypergeometric solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: Could you convert it into a differential equation in a and b?

Comment: `AppellF1[3/2, 1, 1/k, 2, x, k y]` what is: `x` and `y` ? it should probably be: `a` and `b` ?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk $x$ and $y$ are variable. $$ x= \frac{\kappa_x^2-\kappa_y^2}{\kappa_x^2+\kappa_x^2\kappa_y^2\cot^2\theta}, $$ and $$ y=-2u^2\sin^2\theta. $$ Here $\kappa_x$, $\kappa_y$ and $u$ are positive constants.

Comment: Unfortunately, Mathematica has a bug for 'Limit[AppellF1[3/2, 1, 1/k, 2, x, k y],k->0]', as you can see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172425/error-in-integral-representation-of-appells-series)

Comment: Please post yours analytically solution expressed with `a` and `b` and `AppellF1` function ?Update the question, I check in Maple.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Did you see my edit?

Comment: @user3321 Thank you for your edit. Unfortunately you didn't  show  the connection to the integral you asked for (as Mariusz Iwaniuk  asked for...).

Comment: @Ulrich Sorry, but apparently there is no connection between $a$ and $b$. In my first example, these were just constant.

Comment: Please,  if you're working on it, let me know.  :(

Answer (score 5):

*@user3321*: if you report the solution in your possession it is more likely that you can help in finding a trick to use in MMA.

For now, the only thing that comes to mind is to get an idea of the solutions when the positive parameters `a` and `b` change:

```
points = Table[{a, b, NIntegrate[((1 - a Cos[x]^2) Exp[-a/4 Cos[2 x]])/(1 + b Sin[x]^2), 
               {x, 0, Pi/2}]}, {a, 0, 20, .5}, {b, 0, 20, .5}];
ListPointPlot3D[points, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll post my solution soon.

Comment: Did you see my edit?