# Computing numerically infinite sum of some double series

Tags: numerics, summation

Let's consider the series:
    $$
F(t) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}
\frac{(-b)^k(-a)^n\binom{n+k}{k} t^{2n+k(2-\alpha)}}{\Gamma(2n+k(2-\alpha)+2)}
$$

where $a,b$ are positive reals, $0 < \alpha < 1$, and $\Gamma(z)$ is the gamma function.

I would like to numerically compute the sum $F$. I replace the doubly infinite sum by a double finite sum in the following way:

$$
\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\ldots\right) \approx
\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N}\sum\limits_{{n+k = i}\atop{0\leq n,k\leq i}} \left(\ldots\right)
\ \ \ (\star)$$

where bound $N$ is set in such a way, that $\left|\frac{S_{N+1}-S_{N}}{S_{N+1}}\right|<\varepsilon$ ($S_j$ - sum from right hand path of the ($\star$) for $N=j$; $\varepsilon$ - some small number, for example $\varepsilon = 10^{-6}$).

Unfortunately there is something wrong with my approach. For example for $a=1$, $b=1$, $\alpha=0.5$ and $0\leq t \leq 30$ I get following graph:

[image: Graph of approximation of the F(t) for 0\leq t \leq 30]

Definitely, there is something wrong for $t\geq 25$.

My question: How to compute approximation of $F(t)$ correctly also for $t\geq 25$?

Code (in this way I define function $F(t)$):

```
F[t_, α_] := Block[{convergence, N1, S, SN, tab, re, i},
  N1 = 0;
  S = 1;
  convergence = False;
  While[! convergence && N1 <= 1000,
   N1++;
   (* ponizej k = i, n = N1-i *)
   tab = Table[((-v0)^i (-w0^2)^(N1 - i) Binomial[N1, i] t^(
      2 (N1 - i) + i (2 - α)))/
     Gamma[2 (N1 - i) + i (2 - α) + 2], {i, 0, N1}];
   SN = S + Sum[tab[[i]], {i, 1, Length[tab]}];
   re = Abs[(S - SN)/S];
   If[re < 10^-6, convergence = True];
   S = SN;
   ];
  Return[{S, N1, re}];
  ]
```

Comment: Sorry for such strange formating but I could not add this post due to error "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon." (it was some problem with LaTeX code)

Comment: You can probably do one summation symbolically, then your problem should be much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very rough solution I just hacked out; I might try to refine it later.

I had previously talked about [Cuyt's transformation](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01390216) of a double series as an aid in evaluating them numerically in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/169860). Applied to this case, we have

```
Plot[With[{a = 1, b = 1, t = SetPrecision[tx, 25], α = 1/2}, 
          NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit[Accumulate[Table[Sum[
          Function[{n, k}, (-a)^n (-b)^k Binomial[n + k, k] t^(2 n + k (2 - α))/
          Gamma[2 n + k (2 - α) + 2]] @@ v,
          {v, FrobeniusSolve[{1, 1}, k]}], {k, 0, 29}]]]], {tx, 0, 30}, 
     MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> 75, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot]

where I use [`` NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit[] ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/834) for performing the Shanks transformation on the result of Cuyt's transformation.

The method is a bit finicky numerically, which is why I needed the use of `SetPrecision[]`. I also very arbitrarily chose the cutoff `29` in Cuyt's transformation; for other parameter choices, less or more terms might be necessary. All of this will need to be experimented with.

Comment: Thank you for very nice solution of my problem (unfortunately I use version <11.2 of Mathematica, so function NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit[] in unavailable for me)

Comment: Replace that with `SequenceLimit[]`, then.

Comment: It works, thank you :)